# Populate Javascript Object With Data Returned From Program Call

Tags: javascript, object

I have a javascript function that calls an external program and I need to put the result into an object, which will contain multiple rows with multiple values for each, example below:

```
$.get(programcall , function(data) {    
var dealers = {};
data = {0:{'name':'name1','address':'address1','phone':'phone1','miles':1.2},1:{'name':'name2','address':'address2','phone':'phone2','miles':2.2}};
dealers = data;
});
```

This test works because "data" is not enclosed in quotes, however when the content of "data" is returned from the called program, it just becomes text content in "dealers".

How can I get the value stored as an object?

The called program is MINE, so I can change the format if necessary to make it work.
The data will be a list of customers with name, address etc, which I want to process using javascript and to populate a DIV.

Comment: Apologies for not leaving reputation, I don't have enough and Stackoverflow won't allow me to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string is valid JSON, use the native [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function to turn it into an object.

For example:

```
data = JSON.parse('{"mything": 3}')
```

One thing to look out for: JSON needs double quotes around key names, so `{"mything": 3}` works but `{'mything': 3}` [will not validate](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. This also caused the script to abort when I called JSON.parse(), no idea why.  My code currently looks like:

    $.get(programcall , function(data) {
    var dealers = {};
    dealers = JSON.parse(data);
    });

Data is returned as:

    "{0:{"name":"name1","address":"address1","phone":"phone1","miles":1.2},1:{"name":"name2","address":"address2","phone":"phone2","miles":2.2}}"

Comment: @TonyPayne That's not valid json.  You need to string escape those integer keys, like this: `{"0":{"name":"name1","address":"address1","phone":"phone1","miles":1.2},"1":{"name"‌​:"name2","address":"address2","phone":"phone2","miles":2.2}}`

Comment: This validation tool may be helpful in getting the formatting worked out: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thank you, I think jsonlint will be a big help. I'm not very good with json, still learning...

Comment: Nearly there thanks to jsonlint :)   I managed to format my data as {
    "dealers": [
        {
            "name": "name1",
            "address": "address1",
            "phone": "phone1",
            "miles": 1.2
        },
        {
            "name": "name2",
            "address": "address2",
            "phone": "phone2",
            "miles": 2.2
        }
    ]
}

 which when I use "dealers = JSON.parse(data) gives me the format "dealers.dealers" to refer to the content.

Comment: Struggling with formatting this so I just refer to the content as "dealers".  Not sure if I can do it by omitting the outer level from the data, which would probably be better, or if there is a better way of converting the data into an object?

Comment: You can't pass an array as json directly, but you can always just do `dealers = dealers.dealers;` to get the reference you want.

Comment: I had just come to the same conclusion, thanks.  Well I guess that's the best way to do it, at least it works :)  Really appreciate the help, I was all Googled out...

Comment: Of course, happy to help.  And if you could accept my answer that would be awesome. :)

Comment: Ah of course, sorry about that, will accept it now.  JSONLint is proving extremely useful right now.

Answer (score 1):

Your external server call is returning string content as the data object.  This is, hopefully, a valid JSON format but it is still just a string.

What you probably want to do is use [jQuery's getJSON function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) instead of a simple $.get, since it will take care of converting the response to a JSON  object similar to your example.

```
$.getJSON(programcall, function(data) {
   // data is now a JSON object not a string, if it's valid json from your server response
```

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I tried using $_getJSON() instead of just $_get() but the script aborts (I am using Firebug with FF). Not sure why but trying both your suggestion as well as Turtlemonvh below.